# How to use Chai and Mocha for Google Cloud functions unit testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, google-cloud-functions, mocha.js, chai

Having issue in writing simple unit test for Google Cloud Function using Chai, Mocha and Sinon although I am referring [Google unit testing reference doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-http) but unable to understand it.

**Problems**

- I'm getting below error message while running unit test.

```
TypeError: response.status is not a function
```

- Why do I need to typecast Request and Response object while call function? In Google docs example ([Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/e0ae58139eca50a578785624cc46dbc2e91e95c6/functions/helloworld/test/sample.unit.http.test.js#L35)), they are not doing typecasting.

```
onCalculate(req as Request, res as unknown as Response);
```

**Objective:**
Test should pass

**onCalculate.ts**

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const onCalculate = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const param1 = request.body.param1;
  const param2 = request.body.param2;
  response.status(200).send(calculate(param1 as number, param2 as number));
});

/**
 * Function to calculate two numbers
 * @param {number} param1
 * @param {number} param2
 * @return {number}
 */
function calculate(param1: number, param2: number): number {
  return param1 + param2;
}
```

**onCalculate.spec.ts**

```
import firebase from "firebase-functions-test";
import { Request, Response } from "firebase-functions";
import { stub } from "sinon";
import { assert } from "chai";
import { onCalculate } from "./onCalculate";

const test = firebase();

describe("Calculate", () => {
  after(() => {
    test.cleanup();
  });

  it("should return 3", () => {
    const req = {
      query: {},
      body: {
        param1: 1,
        param2: 2,
      },
    };

    const res = { send: stub() };

    onCalculate(req as Request, res as unknown as Response);

    assert.ok(res.send.calledOnce);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stub the `res.status()` method, since `res.status(xxx).send()` is method chain call, you need to use `sinon.stub().returnsThis()` to achieve this.

Sinon.JS ships with a set of assertions that mirror most behavior verification methods and properties on spies and stubs, it's enough. See [assertions](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/assertions/), so you don't need to use `assert` from the `chai` package.

`req` and `res` are mock objects that contain only the properties and methods we need for testing. Not completely satisfied with the `Request` and `Response` interfaces, so we need to use type assertions to tell TSC - "These two objects' shapes are correct". The official repo uses JS, not TS.

E.g.

`onCalculate.ts`:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const onCalculate = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const param1 = request.body.param1;
  const param2 = request.body.param2;
  response.status(200).send(calculate(param1 as number, param2 as number));
});

/**
 * Function to calculate two numbers
 * @param {number} param1
 * @param {number} param2
 * @return {number}
 */
function calculate(param1: number, param2: number): number {
  return param1 + param2;
}
```

`onCalculate.spec.ts`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase-functions-test';
import { Request, Response } from 'firebase-functions';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { onCalculate } from './onCalculate';

const test = firebase();

describe('Calculate', () => {
  after(() => {
    test.cleanup();
  });

  it('should return 3', () => {
    const req = {
      query: {},
      body: {
        param1: 1,
        param2: 2,
      },
    };

    const res = { status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(), send: sinon.stub() };

    onCalculate(req as Request, (res as unknown) as Response);

    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.status, 200);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.send, 3);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
  Calculate
    ✓ should return 3


  1 passing (4ms)

---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                 | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files            |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 onCalculate.spec.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 onCalculate.ts      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```