# Run Chai and Puppeteer Test in Google Cloud Functions not Working

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer, chai

I am running a Script based in Puppeteer, Chai and Mocha that runs locally fine, but not in Google Cloud functions.

I can´t make chai work in Google Cloud Functions.

This is the error I get:

[image: Screenshot Error in Logs]

and this is Code I am using in index.js :

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
//const expect = require('chai')

describe('My First Puppeteer Test', () => {
    let browser
    let page

    before(async function () {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            devtools: false,
        })
        page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.setDefaultTimeout(100000)
        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(20000)
    })

    after(async function () {
        await browser.close()
    })

    beforeEach(async function () {
        //Runs before each Test step
    })

    afterEach(async function () {
        //Runs after each Test step
    })

    it('login', async function () {
        await page.goto('https://my.website.com/user/')

        await page.goto('https://my.website.com/user/')
        await page.waitForSelector('#mat-input-0')
        await page.type('#mat-input-0', 'MyUsername')
        await page.waitForTimeout(1000)
        await page.waitForSelector('#mat-input-1')
        await page.type('#mat-input-1', 'MyPassword')

        await page.waitForTimeout(1000)

        await page.click(
            'body > sbnb-root > sbnb-login > section > article > sbnb-login-form > form > button'
        )
        await page.waitForTimeout(10000)
    })

    it('Go To metrics', async function () {
        await page.goto('https://my.website.com/stadistic')

        //Click Reviews
        await page.waitForSelector(
            'body > sbnb-root > sbnb-exports > div > main > section.create-export-container > div:nth-child(2) > section:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > a'
        )
        await page.click(
            'body > sbnb-root > sbnb-exports > div > main > section.create-export-container > div:nth-child(2) > section:nth-child(2) > div > div.text__small'
        )
        await page.waitForTimeout(10000)




        // Click Single File

        await page.waitForSelector(
            'body > sbnb-root > sbnb-exports > div > main > section.create-export-container > div:nth-child(8) > div:nth-child(1)'
        )
        await page.click(
            'body > sbnb-root > sbnb-exports > div > main > section.create-export-container > div:nth-child(8) > div:nth-child(1)'
        )
        await page.waitForTimeout(10000)


    })



    it('Click send and close', async function () {

    

        // Click Send File

        await page.waitForSelector(
            'body > sbnb-root > sbnb-exports > div > main > section.create-export-container > div.export-final > button'
        )
        await page.click(
            'body > sbnb-root > sbnb-exports > div > main > section.create-export-container > div.export-final > button'
        )
        await page.waitForTimeout(80000)

        
    })

    
})
```

and this is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "sample-http",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha --reporter spec"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.3.4",
        "mocha": "^9.1.3",
        "puppeteer": "^1.20.0"
    }
}
```

How I can I make it work in Google Cloud Functions?

Some ideas about how to rewrite the code just using puppeteer in a way that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-http#system_tests) and a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70521083/), it looks like the proper way to test a Cloud Function is to separate the testing and the actual code to be tested. My suggestion is to build your Puppeteer function and deploy it ([here](https://rominirani.com/using-puppeteer-in-google-cloud-functions-809a14856e14) is a guide for using Puppeteer with Cloud functions), and then perform tests against it, as shown in the documentation.

As for the specific error you are seeing, it [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400459/) that it’s caused by not running the tests through the correct `mocha` commands. You will be able to run these commands by refactoring your code according to the GCP documentation.